# How do I change my variable in this script?

Tags: c#

I feel like my code should be really simple for me to understand, but I keep coming up with the same problem.
float contactWithPlayer = 1;

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SheildMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sizeRandomised = Random.Range(playerModSize, playerModSize);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(sizeRandomised, sizeRandomised, sizeRandomised);
        sideDrift = Random.Range(playerModSideDrift * -1 - 1, playerModSideDrift + 1);
        downSpeed = Random.Range(playerModDownSpeed, playerModDownSpeed + 2);
    }
    //Global Variables

    public int playerModSideDrift;
    public int playerModDownSpeed;
    public float playerModSize;
    float sizeRandomised;

    float sideDrift;
    float downSpeed;

    float contactWithPlayer = 1;


   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(contactWithPlayer);
        Vector3 cloneStats = new Vector3(sideDrift * .01f, -downSpeed * .01f, 0);
        transform.position += cloneStats;


        if (transform.position.y < -10)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            contactWithPlayer = 2;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: I am trying to get the update method to print out contact with Player = 2, but it keeps saying 1.

Comment: @RichardBarker Unlike in Java, In c# `==` can be used to compare string.
@JacobJonis You should better clarify your question.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the property / field definition of `contactWithPlayer` and the context from which these methods are called.

Comment: Yeah of course!

Comment: @bcg that should show the whole script now!

Comment: OT are you sure you want type float for that contactWithPlayer? Int or maybe bool look enough

Comment: Not familiar with Unity, but it seems like you destroy the object as soon as you have set that value to 2, so would you really expect to see that value?

Comment: Well I originally had it set to Bool, but I switched it to a int in order to see if a different type worked, which it didn't.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks so much! it turned out that I was just deleting the game object too soon... thankfully it works great!